# How to create a link to a product by store id?

Tags: php, hyperlink, magento-1.7

Magento 1.7.0.2

2 websites with 2 Store Views per website. 1 website is 'shop' and 1 is 'website'. 'Website' does not have cart or customer/log in functionality but I want to add a button "Shop now!" to the product page view that links to the same product in the 'shop' and it should also be the corresponding Store View (Store Views are Swedish and English).

How can I get the link to the same product as the page "I'm on" but in another Store View (store id)? I have something like this in mind but I don't know how to finish it;

```
if store id == 1
<a class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(store id3).$_product->getUrlKey() ?>">Shop now!</a>
else
<a class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(store id4).$_product->getUrlKey() ?>">Shop now!</a>
endif
```

Any ideas or tips greatly appreciated!

Peter

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if($this->storeid == "1") { ?>

<a class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(store id3).$_product->getUrlKey() ?>">Shop now!</a>

<?php } else { ?>

<a class="button" href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(store id4).$_product->getUrlKey() ?>">Shop now!</a>

<?php } ?>
```

Something like this.. I used $this->storeid as an example variable, don't know which variable you've set with the store ID to do the check :)

Comment: Could you please refine your answer cause my suggestion includes some unfinished parts; the whole href is just written as it should be working, not how I think it actually should be in Magento. For example "getBaseUrl(store id3)" is probably not what Magento expects for getting the base URL of another store id?